# Add active class on click after loading (Ajax) nav html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to add an active class to my nav items after the nav loads. The alert is triggered, but not the active class. Thoughts?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav").load("partials/nav.html", function() {
    $('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems unlikely? If the alert triggers, the class should be added to the clicked LI as well

Comment: I've removed the `.load()` statement and created an active CSS class, your code seems to work just fine. When you inspect the DOM after clicking on an item, does it have the class assigned to it?

Comment: Assuming that's your HTML structure, your code is fine. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/omq1bb37/1/

Comment: It works for me, I just simplified your code by removing the loading of partial view, see here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdmLZx

Comment: Your question needs an **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, mainly the "verifiable" portion.

Comment: what version of jquery are you running?